# javascript news feed to react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, feed

Hi all I have a little problem I would like to convert this logic

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/markets/currencies/economic-calendar/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Economic Calendar</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-events.js" async>
  {
  "colorTheme": "light",
  "isTransparent": false,
  "width": "100%",
  "height": "100%",
  "locale": "en",
  "importanceFilter": "-1,0,1",
  "currencyFilter": "AUD,NZD"
}
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

found here https://www.tradingview.com/widget/economic-calendar/

into a react component

after a number of iterations, I managed to make write this logic

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const useScript = url => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const config = {
            "colorTheme": "light",
            "isTransparent": false,
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%",
            "locale": "en",
            "importanceFilter": "-1,0,1",
            "currencyFilter": "AUD,NZD"
        }
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        script.async = true;

        script.innerText =config;
        document.body.appendChild(script);


        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        }
    }, [url]);
};

export default useScript;
```

The issue is I do not know how or where to insert the "config" so I can set the size to auto and so I can filter the data down to just displaying news from new Zealand and Oz, I have tried just printing it out and appending it a child of script any help would be greatly appreciated